# Spring security 4: Access denied for admin role

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am learning Spring Security. My user `admin123` has authority `admin`. I have an `admin.jsp` which should be accessible only to user with admin authority.

Security configuration xml has

`<security:intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasRole('admin')" />`
which doesn't seem to work. Administration page is not accessible even after logging in with user `admin123`.

Not able to figure out the issue. Please help.

Comment: post you queries also for getting admin data

Comment: Make sure you put the `admin.jsp` in inside the repository `/admin`. Otherwhise please post the used query

Comment: i am using the default tables users and authorities.
users-by-username-query:
`select username, password, enabled from dbo.users where username=?`

authorities-by-username-query:
`select username, authority from dbo.authorities where username=?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved. forgot to update here.

Instead of hasRole('admin'), hasAuthority('admin') needs to be used in these scenarios. hasRole() can be used only if role is mentioned in a particular format. ie, 'ROLE_ADMIN'

So hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') as well as hasAuthority('admin') work.